# How to run php on web browser?

Tags: php, mysql, web

I used to open any php file but now it doesn't.
I have been using Appserv for a while, and I have to start appache and then open the file.
This is how I used to open a php file on web browser
`C:\AppServ\www\myfile.php`
Am I missing something?

Comment: Make sure that your apache server is running and then open the browser and write: http://localhost/myfile.php then hit enter.

Comment: Check if everything is still running, specially webserver, everything shold run as as a service

Comment: Well I ran everything again, like appache and mysql.
And what I get is bunch of codes.

Comment: file:///C:/AppServ/www/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php
this is what wordpress says i have to write in URL to setup wordpress but it shows the codes..
I have plugins installed, did many things a year ago

Answer (score 0):

You can't run PHP in a web browser.

For web programming, PHP is used as a *server-side* language.

You need to configure a web server to execute it, and then request the URL for the PHP program with the browser.

Comment: It used to show,
and now even I am trying to run wordpress which again what I used to do, I get bunch of codes, it shows html and css as codes.